# Backbone Collection filter method

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, collections, filtering

Can someone explain the mechanics behind the filter() method that exists within the Collection "class"?  The Backbone API for this method appears inconsistent with the following example implementation (taken from the Todo exercise @ http://addyosmani.github.io/backbone-fundamentals/):

```
completed: function() {
    return this.filter(function( todo ) {
        return todo.get('completed');
    });
}
```

This code snippet produces an array of model objects who's 'completed' property contains "true".  However, I cannot come close to understanding how an array of objects is returned from this function

Answer (score 1):

The key to your curiosity lies in underscores source code. As you probably already know, a large number of methods available to you on a Backbone.Collection are brought in from underscore.

Let's take a look at how they do that first:

```
// Underscore methods that we want to implement on the Collection.
// 90% of the core usefulness of Backbone Collections is actually implemented
// right here:
var methods = ['forEach', 'each', 'map', 'collect', 'reduce', 'foldl',
'inject', 'reduceRight', 'foldr', 'find', 'detect', 'filter', 'select',
'reject', 'every', 'all', 'some', 'any', 'include', 'contains', 'invoke',
'max', 'min', 'toArray', 'size', 'first', 'head', 'take', 'initial', 'rest',
'tail', 'drop', 'last', 'without', 'difference', 'indexOf', 'shuffle',
'lastIndexOf', 'isEmpty', 'chain'];

// Mix in each Underscore method as a proxy to `Collection#models`.
_.each(methods, function(method) {
    Collection.prototype[method] = function() {

      // Important: BOLT ON THE COLLECTION MODELS TO THE ARGUMENTS.
      var args = slice.call(arguments);
      args.unshift(this.models);

      // .apply (since we have an array of arguments).
      return _[method].apply(_, args);
    };
});
```

So we have a list of underscore method names. The source code loops through those method names and adds each one to your collections prototype. Important: You'll notice that this code patches the argument list to include in your collection's models.

Now look at underscore's actual method implementation:

```
_.filter = _.select = function(obj, iterator, context) {
  var results = [];
  if (obj == null) return results;
  if (nativeFilter && obj.filter === nativeFilter) return obj.filter(iterator, context);

  each(obj, function(value, index, list) {
    if (iterator.call(context, value, index, list)) results.push(value);
  });

  return results;
}
```

You'll notice that filter just wraps around each and cycles through the passed in object (properties). All the backbone version does is put this method into context to save you from having to pass in the models each time.

Answer (score 0):

```
return todo.get('completed');
```

basically corresponds to this

```
return todo.get('completed') === true ;
```

So all the `todo Models` in the collection whole attribute **completed** is set to **true** will be returned from the innermost return statement

And the outermost return will Return the collection of all the models whose condition is satisfied by the filter function..

This can simply be written as

```
completed: function() {
    var filteredModels =  this.filter(function( todo ) {
        return todo.get('completed');
    });

    return filteredModels;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Filter method creates empty array for results and loop through the `this.models`. And if `iterator` function returns truthly value the model is pushed to the results array.
In your example `iterator` is

```
function (todo) {
  return todo.get('completed');
}
```

`iterator` returns some value that is checked for truthly

```
// simplified call
if (iterator()) results.push(value)
```

Answer (score -1):

here the completed function is a filtering function to display only the todo completed

Since backbone extends underscore here

the filtered method of undescore is called which normally does

```
filter_.filter(list, iterator, [context]) Alias: select
```

Looks through each value in the list, returning an array of all the values that pass a truth test (iterator). Delegates to the native filter method, if it exists.

Meaning that the todo.get is passed on each model in the collection and this is to test each model for their completed state if true the model is return in the array of the function

Comment: Please note that your answers should address the *specific* question being asked directly; not simply provide a block of code that seems to do what the asker wants.